# For loops python problems

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Write a function that takes as an input parameter a string and a number n and returns a newly created string made of every nth letter.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at any string methods, in particular `slice notation`?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple in Python because of the way it handles indexing:

```
def every_n(s, n):
    return s[::n]
```

That third item between the colons says "every n".

Check out [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation/509295#509295) for a more in depth description of how to slice in Python.

Comment: def forstrings(string,n):
    for x in string[:n]:
        print str(x)

forstrings("denmark",2)